# Space in doskey/alias for windows?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, alias, bash-alias

I try to run [Laravel's Artisan](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan) command inside the (docker) container by defining a doskey alias.

My idea was:

```
php artisan=docker-compose exec apache php artisan $1
```

However it does not allow me to use a space in the key. Any idea how to achieve this?

[image: image showing "invalid macro definition" error]

**edit** I have made a little GUI tool for Windows to run the commands https://github.com/thomasmoors/DockerArtisan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I must in this case give a negative answer - using blanks in a doskey name is impossible.
Doskey was created for the Command Prompt (cmd), so is rather simple in concept.

This is impossible in my opinion since :

- In a doskey command such as `doskey a b=ab`, it takes "a" for an invalid option
- The doskey command does not accept quotes around the macro name.

Here are some tests I have run :

[image]

As you can see, some special characters are accepted, but just not blanks.

Even without blanks in the macro name,
doskey is an old DOS program and can only work in PowerShell with difficulty.
It conflicts with the `PSReadLine` module which relies on the native console input functions. I tested this :

[image: image2]

As you can see, you need to do two additional actions :

- Issue the command `Remove-Module PSReadLine`
- Add to the doskey command the parameter `/exename=powershell.exe`

When both are done, the command is executed correctly and gives the
right error.

My best advice is not to use doskey in PowerShell.
Doskey is old and PowerShell is new, and they can only be used together
with difficulty.
I really don't think that doskey is so useful as to be irreplaceable.

Try to find another solution to your often-used commands.
For example, store the commands in in executable files such as `.ps1`
or `.cmd` or `.bat` inside a folder that you would add to the PATH.

Comment: Why do I get
```
php_artisan : The term 'docker-compose exec apache php /home/medpets/WWW/laravel/artisan' is not recognized as the name
 of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, ve
rify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ php_artisan list
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (docker-compose ...laravel/artisan:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: It's hard to understand from a comment. Could you please add a screenshot.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/XyXQCdx

Comment: Thanks, please also include your doskey command.

Comment: `New-Alias php_artisan "docker-compose exec apache php /home/medpets/WWW/laravel/artisan"`

Comment: OK, I got it and modified my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution for this is to create `.bat` file and run it with parameters. I use this solution to run `magento2` commands.
**Example:**

```
@ECHO OFF
IF "%1"=="clean" (
    php bin/magento c:c & goto :exit

)  
:exit
```

file name: `magento.bat` and when i type `magento clean` it runs `php bin/magento c:c`.

Comment: nice workaround +1

Comment: Interesting, but if the alias (.bat file) and the program names are the same, the program takes precedence.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to achieve this. Doskey macroname cannot have a space in it.

Comment: Is there a workaround?

Comment: How about adding a "_" between or without added space, or something similar (like php_artisan or phpartisan)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's just one example of what makes allowing spaces in command names difficult:

say I define two macros:

```
doskey a b=echo 'ran cmd [a b] with input ' $*
doskey a b c=echo 'ran cmd [a b c] with input ' $*
```

If you type the command `C:\src>a b c efg` how could the interpreter know if you meant `run cmd [a b] with input [c efg]` or `run cmd [a b c] with input [efg]`. This applies to any executable, not just doskey commands, and if you tried to work around it you would potentially limit the input a command can take based on other commands that start with the same name.